# How to host web application in apache tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, hosting, java, jsp

I created a small web application in Java using eclipse. Now I want to host it in apache in my local machine. How to do this? I want some simple instructions not very technical details.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using  [Eclipse IDE for **Java EE** developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1), it is easy to create dynamic web projects and directly integrate Tomcat.

Do the following steps in Eclipse:

1. Open the *Servers* view in the bottom box, rightclick there and choose *New > Server*. Pick the appropriate Tomcat version and complete the wizard.
2. Create new **dynamic web project** in Eclipse which is associated with the integrated Tomcat. Open the *Project Navigator* on the left hand side. Rightclick there and choose *New > Project* and then in menu *Web > Dynamic Web Project* and set the *Target Runtime* to the Tomcat.
3. Deploy the web app to Tomcat from within Eclipse by choosing "Right click Servlet src > Run on Server" This will open a browser and you can test your app